# How to make images resize with the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I  have a jQuery slider that displays images and I'm trying to get it to be responsive. Here is a codepen with the exact example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/plvsq

As you can see the images do not re-size if the browser is made smaller or bigger. I have tried using

```
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

but this did nothing. I am trying to achieve an effect like the re-sizing banner on this site: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/plvsq

Comment: It seems to resize fine after editing css div and zooming in and out.

Comment: img {width:100%; min-width: 100%; height: auto; }

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yErts

Answer (score 0):

```
.sliderItem { float: left; position: relative; width:100%;}
.sliderItem div { min-width: 100%; width:100%}
.sliderItem img { min-width: 100%; width:100%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5L1jmjy5/

```
#sliderWrapper{ 
    min-width : 300px;
    min-height : 150px;
    overflow : hidden;
    position : relative;
    margin : 0 auto;
}

@media (max-width : 1400px){
    #sliderList li { max-width:1400px; }
    #sliderWrapper{ max-width:1400px; height:350px; }
}

@media (max-width : 1200px){
    #sliderList li { max-width:1200px; }
    #sliderWrapper{ max-width:1200px; height:300px; }
}

@media  (max-width : 900px){
    #sliderList li { max-width:900px; }
    #sliderWrapper{ max-width:900px; }
    #sliderWrapper{ max-width:1200px; height:250px; }
}

@media  (max-width : 768px){
    #sliderList li { max-width:768px; }
    #sliderWrapper{ max-width:768px; height:200px; }
}

@media  (max-width : 300px){
    #sliderList li { max-width:300px; }
    #sliderWrapper { max-width:300px; height:150px; }
}

.sliderItem div { width:100%; }
.sliderItem img { width:100%; min-height:150px; }
```

Here, is the example which work's using ccs3 media query method. If you want to do without css media query then use less or jquery.